# How can I confirm a database is Oracle & what version it is using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm building an installer for an application. The user gets to select a datasource they have configured and nominate what type of database it is.  I want to confirm that the database type is indeed Oracle, and if possible, what version of Oracle they are running by sending a SQL statement to the datasource.

Comment: What about your programming language? This kind of question really depends on the language API for the DB access.

Comment: I can assume I have a JDBC datasource.  If the connection fails, or the sql statement generates and error then I can certainly trap that and treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 297, accepted):

Run this SQL:

```
select * from v$version;
```

And you'll get a result like:

```
BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.3.0      Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

Comment: All versions of Oracle I have ever used.  I can't speak for Oracle 5.0 and before!

Comment: This technique failed for me on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0, but I am having some login permission problems.

However, for those that might be in the same boat as me, the second technique mentioned on this page by Lawrence did work:
select * from product_component_version

Comment: Doesn't work if you don't have permission to v$views. [Lawrence's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/101248/345659) has an answer for that

Comment: @TonyAndrews: What is the output like when select * from v$version; fails?

Comment: @AtmeshMishra: I'm not sure - maybe `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`?  What do you get?

Comment: @TonyAndrews : I can't replicate a failed situation! Thats why I am asking around! :)

Comment: When I run this I get `ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.v$version' doesn't exist`. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: @PauseUnpause It looks like you are using MySQL and not Oracle?

Comment: @TonyAndrews yes. Is there any universal command to return the type of database I am using, and the version of SQL?

Comment: @PauseUnpause No I'm afraid not

Answer (score 49):

Two methods:

```
select * from v$version;
```

will give you:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
CORE 11.1.0.6.0 Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
```

OR [Identifying Your Oracle Database Software Release](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/dba.htm#ADMIN11032):

```
select * from product_component_version;
```

will give you:

```
PRODUCT VERSION STATUS
NLSRTL  11.1.0.6.0  Production
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition  11.1.0.6.0  64bit Production
PL/SQL  11.1.0.6.0  Production
TNS for Solaris:    11.1.0.6.0  Production
```

Comment: great... i needed product_component_version.. as i didnt have access to v$ views

Comment: That second query is far more suitable for automatic checking, as it requires defines a data format, rather than relying on ad-hoc parsing. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 32):

```
SQL> SELECT version FROM v$instance;
VERSION
-----------------
11.2.0.3.0
```

Comment: Best answer since it just gives the version number only, hence no need to parse the output to extract version in an automated script.

Comment: @omeinush Works perfectly with me (11.2.0.3 ).

Comment: @tjati It appears to be dependent not on the version, but on the user permissions. `V$INSTANCE` is apparently not globally available by default.

Comment: It does not work on Oracle 18c:       SQL> SELECT version FROM v$instance;
SELECT version FROM v$instance
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Requires dba privilege.

Answer (score 8):

You can either use

```
SELECT * FROM v$version;
```

or

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
EXEC dbms_output.put_line( dbms_db_version.version );
```

if you don't want to parse the output of v$version.

Answer (score 3):

If your instance is down, you are look for version information in alert.log

Or another crude way is to look into Oracle binary, If DB in hosted on Linux, try strings on Oracle binary.

```
strings -a $ORACLE_HOME/bin/oracle |grep RDBMS | grep RELEASE
```

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to check Oracle Database Version. Easiest way is to run the below SQL query to check [Oracle Version](https://orahow.com/oracle-plsql-checking-oracle-version-information/).

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;
```

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM v$version;
```

Answer (score 2):

For Oracle use:

```
Select * from v$version;
```

For SQL server use:

```
Select @@VERSION as Version
```

and for MySQL use:

```
Show variables LIKE "%version%";
```

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL statement:

```
select edition,version from v$instance
```

returns:

- database edition eg. "XE"
- database version eg. "12.1.0.2.0"

(select privilege on the v$instance view is of course necessary)

Comment: @Prokhozhii - We now use 19 so i can no longer confirm but I would appreciate it if you could provide additional explanation  as select version from v$instance definitely works in Oracle 11 . See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8135737/3051627 above. (are you 100% sure the user has access to v$instance on your database?)

Comment: SQL> select edition,version from v$instance;
select edition,version from v$instance
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "EDITION": invalid identifier

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_2002.htm

Answer (score 0):

We can use the below Methods to get the version Number of Oracle.

Method No : 1

```
set serveroutput on;
BEGIN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION || '.' || DBMS_DB_VERSION.RELEASE); 
END;
```

Method No : 2

```
SQL> select *
  2  from v$version;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work starting from Oracle 10

```
select version
      , regexp_substr(banner, '[^[:space:]]+', 1, 4) as edition 
from    v$instance
     ,  v$version where regexp_like(banner, 'edition', 'i');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_which_edition
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS

    /*

        Purpose: determine which database edition

        MODIFICATION HISTORY
        Person      Date        Comments
        ---------   ------      -------------------------------------------
        dcox        6/6/2013    Initial Build

    */

    -- Banner
    CURSOR c_get_banner
    IS
        SELECT banner
          FROM v$version
         WHERE UPPER(banner) LIKE UPPER('Oracle Database%');

    vrec_banner c_get_banner%ROWTYPE; -- row record
    v_database VARCHAR2(32767); --

BEGIN
    -- Get banner to get edition
    OPEN c_get_banner;
    FETCH c_get_banner INTO vrec_banner;
    CLOSE c_get_banner;

    -- Check for Database type
    IF INSTR( UPPER(vrec_banner.banner), 'EXPRESS') > 0
    THEN
        v_database := 'EXPRESS';
    ELSIF INSTR( UPPER(vrec_banner.banner), 'STANDARD') > 0
    THEN
        v_database := 'STANDARD';
    ELSIF INSTR( UPPER(vrec_banner.banner), 'PERSONAL') > 0
    THEN
        v_database := 'PERSONAL';
    ELSIF INSTR( UPPER(vrec_banner.banner), 'ENTERPRISE') > 0
    THEN
        v_database := 'ENTERPRISE';
    ELSE
        v_database := 'UNKNOWN';
    END IF;

    RETURN v_database;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        RETURN 'ERROR:' || SQLERRM(SQLCODE);
END fn_which_edition; -- function fn_which_edition
/
```

Done.