# How can I confirm a database is Postgres & what version it is using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm building an installer for an application. The user gets to select a datasource they have configured and nominate what type of database it is.  I want to confirm that the database type is indeed Postgres, and if possible, what version of Postgres they are running by sending a SQL statement to the datasource.

Comment: Stop duplicating questions! <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101184/how-can-i-confirm-a-database-is-oracle-what-version-it-is-using-sql>

Comment: They're not duplicate questions. My research to date suggests you need quite different approaches to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mk=# SELECT version();
                                            version                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 8.3.3 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.2.3 (Ubuntu 4.2.3-2ubuntu7)
(1 row)
```

The command works too in MySQL:

```
mysql> select version();
+--------------------------------+
| version()                      |
+--------------------------------+
| 5.0.32-Debian_7etch1~bpo.1-log | 
+--------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

There is no version command in sqlite as far as I can see.

Answer (score 4):

`SHOW server_version;`

(for completeness)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT version();
```

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has a version() function you can call.

```
SELECT version();
```

It will return something like this:

```
                                            version
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 8.3.3 on i486-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.2.3 (Ubuntu 4.2.3-2ubuntu7)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is DB dependent, and in case this function exists in another dbms, this says PostgreSQL in the output

```
select version()
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting ... version() is a function! I wonder why? Version is not going to change or return different values under different inputs/circumstances.

Curious because I remember from old days that in Sybase it used to be a global variable and version could be found out by doing "select @@version"