# How to insert records from multiple rows in a table into single rows (group my ID) in other table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, group-by

I have a table with records  as:

```
ID  |NAME   |FULLNAME
ID1 |John   |John S
ID1 |Tom    |Tom S
ID2 |Tin    |Tin J
ID2 |Jim    |Jim B
ID2 |Kethy  |Kethy T
ID3 |Neo    |Neo L
```

I want to create a new table and insert the records as below :

```
ID  |NAME1  |FULLNAME1  |NAME2  |FULLNAME2  |NAME3         |FULLNAME3
ID1 |John   |John S     |Tom    |Tom S      
ID2 |Tin    |Tin J      |Jim    |Jim B      |Kethy         |Kethy T
ID3 |Neo    |Neo L
```

The structure of the new table is fixed with 7 columns in total.

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT name1.id
     , name1.name AS name1
     , name1.fullname AS fullname1
     , name2.name AS name2
     , name2.fullname AS fullname2
     , name3.name AS name3
     , name3.fullname AS fullname3
  FROM ( SELECT * 
           FROM ( SELECT id, name, fullname
                       , rank() over ( partition by id order by fullname asc) as rank 
                    FROM old_table )
          WHERE rank = 1) name1
     , ( SELECT * 
           FROM ( SELECT id, name, fullname
                       , rank() over ( partition by id order by fullname asc) as rank 
                    FROM old_table )
          WHERE rank = 2) name2
     , ( SELECT * 
           FROM ( SELECT id, name, fullname
                       , rank() over ( partition by id order by fullname asc) as rank 
                    FROM old_table ) 
          WHERE rank = 3) name3
 WHERE name1.id = name2.id (+)
   AND name1.id = name3.id (+)
 ORDER BY name1.id ASC;
```

There may be some ways to optimize it somehow but it seems to produce the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

if your database version is 11g or higher you can use the pivot function , which can transfer rows into columns.
examples here : http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

to determine what is your database version : [How can I confirm a database is Oracle & what version it is using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101184/how-can-i-confirm-a-database-is-oracle-what-version-it-is-using-sql)

```
select * from v$version;
```