# Format Datetime Column - ODBC connection to Composite Information Server

Tags: sql, datetime-format

I'm provided with Composite Software driver using which I've created a **ODBC connection** and fetching data. I'm not able to find the syntax as how to format the datetime. I tried this -

```
select MY_DATE from Master_Table
```

I get the value as 9/3/2013 12:00:00 AM. I want to format it as 9/3/2013 without time and I need to concat it with another column.

I tried the following query based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) manual -

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(30), MY_DATE, 103) AS Expr1 FROM Master_Table
```

And I get the error -

> SQL Execution Error.
>
> Executed SQL statement: SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(30), MY_DATE, 103) AS
>   Expr1 FROM Master_Table Error Source: Composite Software 6.1.0 ODBC
>   Driver Error Message: ERROR [HY000] Unable to parse query text: 
>   Incorrect syntax near "SELECT", found "CONVERT".  On line 1, column 8.
>       [parser-2904201] Cause: Incorrect syntax near "SELECT", found "CONVERT"

The problem is I have no idea how to find sql syntax for [Composite Information Server](http://www.compositesw.com/products-services/information-server/). Or will the SQL syntax will be same for all ODBC connections? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The ODBC driver doesn't appear to support the syntax - you really need to manual for the database driver to determine what you can do. An alternative is to pull the data across to a MSSQL server and query it there (you could add it as a linked server using the same driver)

Comment: See if there's any more info in the properties of the driver you used to set up the ODBC DSN; ask the DB admin; try lots of simple queries using vendor specific SQL features to work out what DB is being used. PostgreSQL has a `::` CASTing shortcut which may be unique to that DB, for example. Here's an 'Oracle Detector' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101184/how-can-i-confirm-a-database-is-oracle-what-version-it-is-using-sql

Comment: I tried TO_CHAR(MY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') and it is working. Seems to work with PL-SQL sytax.