# Unable to get version of Oracle database

Tags: oracle, aqua-data-studio

Finding version of Oracle database should be easy. As written here: [How can I confirm a database is Oracle & what version it is using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101184/how-can-i-confirm-a-database-is-oracle-what-version-it-is-using-sql) it's one command:

```
select * from v$version;
```

However it seems to be not working on some specific versions of Oracle. My database throws following exception while executing the command:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-1 -------------------------- 
>   ORA-00911: invalid character 
>   Script line 1, statement line 1, column 23

I use Aqua Data Studio 15.0.14 to connect with DBMS.

Comment: The statement is fine. To me it looks like this Aqua Studio thing messes with your statement.

Comment: If the Aqua Data Studio issue is resolved, can you mark as the accepted answer ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've checked correct answer but it's been deleted. I'm going to verify your answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select * from v$version
go
Aqua Data Studio uses go or / as statement separator. You can change this behavior under File-> Options.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;`