# How to find oracle's version I connected with toad?

Tags: oracle, toad

Like title says, I want to know oracle's version I connected with toad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I confirm a database is Oracle & what version it is using SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101184/how-can-i-confirm-a-database-is-oracle-what-version-it-is-using-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/171827/how-can-i-find-my-oracle-10g-server-version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use this query command to find oracle's version.

```
select * from v$version
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have access to v$version or v$instance, you can run this code. Be sure to turn on DBMS Output.

```
BEGIN 
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION || '.' || DBMS_DB_VERSION.RELEASE); 
END;
```

You can also run `select * from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION;`